# Looping Python Parameters Through SQL Code

Tags: python, sql, for-loop

I need to create the following report scalable:

```
query = """
(SELECT
    '02/11/2019' as Week_of,
    media_type,
    campaign,
    count(ad_start_ts) as frequency
FROM usotomayor.digital 
WHERE ds between 20190211 and 20190217
GROUP BY 1,2,3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
    '02/18/2019' as Week_of,
    media_type,
    campaign,
    count(ad_start_ts) as frequency
FROM usotomayor.digital 
WHERE ds between 20190211 and 20190224
GROUP BY 1,2,3)


"""

#Converting to dataframe
query2 = spark.sql(query).toPandas()
query2
```

However, as you can see I cannot make this report scalable if I have a long list of dates for each SQL query that I need to union.

My first attempt at looping in a list of date variables into the SQL script is as follows:

```
dfys = ['20190217','20190224']

df2 = ['02/11/2019','02/18/2019']

for i in df2:
    date=i

for j in dfys:
    date2=j

query = f"""
SELECT
    '{date}' as Week_of,
    raw.media_type,
    raw.campaign,
    count(raw.ad_start_ts) as frequency
FROM usotomayor.digital raw 
WHERE raw.ds between 20190211 and {date2}
GROUP BY 1,2,3

"""

#Converting to dataframe
query2 = spark.sql(query).toPandas()
query2
```

However, this is not working for me. I think I need to loop through the sql query itself, but I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: "this is not working for me" — Perhaps you could be more specific.

Comment: When I run the code with the Python loop it only runs the last set of the variable array list.

Comment: indentions are incorrect so I can only say you have to do it inside `for`-loop, not after `for`-loop.  You can create list with all SELECT and later concatenate them with `"\nUNION ALL\n".join(list_with_all_SELECT)`

Answer (score 3):

As a commenter said "this is not working for me" is not very specific so let's start at specifying the problem. You need to execute a query for each pair of dates you need to execute these queries as a loop and save the result (or actually union them, but then you need to change your query logic).

You could do it like this:

```
dfys = ['20190217', '20190224']

df2 = ['02/11/2019', '02/18/2019']

query_results = list()
for start_date, end_date in zip(dfys, df2):
    query = f"""
    SELECT
        '{start_date}' as Week_of,
        raw.media_type,
        raw.campaign,
        count(raw.ad_start_ts) as frequency
    FROM usotomayor.digital raw 
    WHERE raw.ds between 20190211 and {end_date}
    GROUP BY 1,2,3

    """
    query_results.append(spark.sql(query).toPandas())

query_results[0]
query_results[1]
```

Now you get a list of your results (query_results).

Comment: Thank you SO much for this answer! After more than a dozen searches, I finally stumbled upon it and it was exactly what I needed! You’re so helpful and I appreciate your clear, correct, and applicable answer!